# How can i differentiate real face vs fake face in iPhone and iPad application?

Tags: objective-c, swift3, face-detection

I am developing an iPhone application where I want to work on face liveness. A clear idea is spoofing of a person is not allowed. Does anyone implemented it or know-how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do exactly is *not clear*.

Face identification of the device owner is available through `LocalAuthentication` and biometrics, have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id?language=objc).

If you instead need to understand if the face you're seeing is a real person (and not just a photo) maybe take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997240/how-to-find-out-detected-face-is-real-or-fake) and [this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/03/11/liveness-detection-with-opencv/).

Also please provide some more information on what you're trying to accomplish and some code of what you've already tried.

Comment: I want to check the liveness of person. Like it will say person is showing photo to camera or if it's the real person then it will show the real person.

Comment: Then have a look at the last article I've linked, that's exactly what it does using OpenCV. [Here](https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/face-recognition-with-opencv/#using-opencv-on-ios) it show how you could integrate OpenCV with iOS

Comment: Thanks i'll check.

Comment: I have gone through the link you share but not able to find out exact solution can you please help me.